# Getting undefined object error in Typescript using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I am following the Traversy Media new [Angular crash course]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dHNOWTI7H8 around 39:45 and getting object undefined errors constantly.

Here is the picture of the error which says object is possibly 'undefined':
[object is possibly 'undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBI9O.png)

This worked in task-item.component.html

```
<p *ngFor="let task of tasks">
  {{task.text}}
</p>
```

This object is possibly 'undefined' task-item.component.html

```
<div class="task">
    <h3>{{task.text}}</h3>
    <p>{{task.day}}</p>
</div>
```

task-item.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import {Task} from 'src/Task';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-task-item',
      templateUrl: './task-item.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./task-item.component.css']
    })
    export class TaskItemComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() task?: Task;
    
      constructor() {
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```

I have put a tsconfig.json rule "strictPropertyInitialization": false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you set it as a an optional using ?

You can either remove ? which is not a good practice if your item can be null, or you can just do this in the html

```
<div class="task">
  <h3>{{task?.text}}</h3>
  <p>{{task?.day}}</p>
</div>
```

It will display the value if the variable is initialized, and don't throw an error

Answer (score 2):

The `?` here indicates that this is a nullable object.

```
@Input() task?: Task;
```

If you always pass task to `app-task-item` then just remove the `?`

```
@Input() task: Task;
```

Or you can add a conditional in your html, and remove the `?` in your `.ts`

```
@Input() task: Task;
...
<div class="task">
  <h3>{{task?.text}}</h3>
  <p>{{task?.day}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not passing a value into `task` when you instantiate the component, which  than it would be undefined.

If are ever going to instantiate `task-item` without a task input you could add something like this to your ngOnInit

```
const blankTask: Task = {
  text: 'placeholder text',
  day: 'placeholder day',
};
...
ngOnInit() {
    this.task = this.task || blankTask;
  }
```

This means you do not always have to pass in a task to the component.
Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tzur1z?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I add *ngIf

```
  <div class="task" *ngIf="task">
      <h3>{{task.text}}</h3> 
      <p>{{task.day}}</p> 
    </div>
```